# Add new line to end of each row

Tags: notepad++

Folks,

I've a .txt file with 6,000 rows.

I had to remove all \n new rows in the data initially as there was some spurious figures in it which was causing some rows to split e.g. instead of there being 6,000 rows there was 6,100 when viewed in notepad++.

Is there any way I can add new row (\n) to the end of each line so I can read my data into SAS?

Any help welcome

Comment: post an example of how the txt looks like and what you need to look like

Comment: I think you just need to disable `Word Wrap`